# PDOL enough for online processing

Tags: contactless-smartcard, emv, tlv

I Have successfully generated a ARQC by fulfilling the PDOL requirements as requested by the ICC (VISA). I would like to force all transactions with online PIN validation, irrespective of floor limits, pin try limits etc.

Do I need to still do another generate AC command or is the below sufficient to submit for online processing ?

```
Response Message Template Format 2 [77]:
    Application Interchange Profile (AIP) [82]:
        Data (Binary):  20 00
        Bit flags set:
        1Bxb8: 0 - RFU
        1Bxb7: 0 - Off-line SDA is not supported
        1Bxb6: 1 - Off-line DDA is supported
        1Bxb5: 0 - Cardholder verification is not supported
        1Bxb4: 0 - Terminal risk management not required
        1Bxb3: 0 - Issuer Authentication not supported
        1Bxb2: 0 - RFU
        1Bxb1: 0 - CDA not supported
        2Bxb8: 0 - MSD not supported (Contactless value)
        2Bxb7: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb6: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb5: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb4: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb3: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb2: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb1: 0 - RFU
    Application File Locator (AFL) [94]:
        Data (Binary):  10 02 02 00 10 05 06 00 10 03 03 00
    Track 2 Equivalent Data [57]:
        Data (Binary):  pp pp pp pp pp pp pp pp D2 20 72 26 00 00 00 03 43 00 0F
    Cardholder Name [5F20]:
        Data (Binary):  20 2F
        Data (ASCII):    /
    Issuer Application Data (IAD) [9F10]:
        Data (Binary):  06 01 11 03 A0 00 00 0F 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E0 68 76 3A
    Application Cryptogram (AC) [9F26]:
        Data (Binary):  FB 61 6D 9B 3F FC 00 7E
    Cryptogram Information Data (CID) [9F27]:
        Data (Binary):  80
    Application Transaction Counter (ATC) [9F36]:
        Data (Binary):  cc cc
    Card Transaction Qualifiers (CTQ) [9F6C]:
        Data (Binary):  3E 40
        Bit flags set:
        1Bxb8: 0 - Online PIN not Required
        1Bxb7: 0 - Signature Not Required
        1Bxb6: 1 - Go Online if Offline Data Authentication Fails and Reader is online capable.
        1Bxb5: 1 - Switch Interface if Offline Data Authentication fails and Reader supports VIS.
        1Bxb4: 1 - Go Online if Application Expired
        1Bxb3: 1 - Switch Interface for Cash Transactions
        1Bxb2: 1 - Switch Interface for Cashback Transactions
        1Bxb1: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb8: 0 - Consumer Device CVM not Performed
        2Bxb7: 1 - Card supports Issuer Update Processing at the POS
        2Bxb6: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb5: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb4: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb3: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb2: 0 - RFU
        2Bxb1: 0 - RFU
    Customer Exclusive Data (CED) [9F7C]:
        Data (Binary):  00 00 00 00
    Form Factor Indicator (qVSDC) [9F6E]:
        Data (Binary):  20 70 00 00
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the below CVM contactless limit on the terminal to zero? this should force the CVM( but are you particular on Online PIN ? what about signature or CDCVM . What if the issuer does not support Online PIN )

Comment: For this solution, I would like to force each transaction for online PIN validation, most of the issuers in South Africa supports online PIN. I will set CVM to zero and try to force it in that manner.

Comment: If this is not a local regulatory requirement, refer payment scheme guidelines also. And also you should consider cards issued outside your region also. The expectation and experience should not conflict later.

Answer (score 1):

According the provided reply the CTQ Tag 0x9F6C there is no Online PIN, Signature or CDCVM required by card. Card Application expired and require to get final authorisation/approval online.

To force card to request Online PIN for all transactions you may set Floor limit to zero and exclude all other CVMs from Terminal Transaction Qualifiers (TTQ) Tag 0x9F66.
Up to your terminal configuration preferences to support Signature or CDCVM.